# Typing Object.values(users).forEach

Tags: typescript

I was wondering how to fix this code, if I change the type of room to string on `forEach((room: string)` I got this error:

> Argument of type '(room: string) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: unknown, index: number, array: unknown[]) => void'.
> Types of parameters 'room' and 'value' are incompatible.
> Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'string'.

Otherwise if I leave blank, I had to convert `room as string` on the line `batch.update`.

```
Object.values(users).forEach((room: string) => {
  batch.set(firestore.collection('messages').doc(), {
    ...message,
    room,
  })

  batch.update(firestore.collection('rooms').doc(room), { // if I leave room as `unknow` I have an error here.
     ...
  })
})
```

What is the correctly way to fix the typing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply declared the callback argument type should just be fine.

```js
Object.values<string>(users).forEach(s => /* ... */)
```

Comment: Perfect. Thannk you!